# How do I use nth-child to select divs with specific class when divs exist in between?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html codes that has a foundation grid. I want to show a border on the right ,except for the items that are at the end of each breakpoint. For example, on `small` I would want the right border on items 1 and 3.On `large` I want the right border on items 1, 2 and 4.

```
<div class="row with-right-border " data-equalizer="bad5n8-equalizer" data-equalize-on="small" data-resize="qotd5r-eq" data-mutate="tow7yb-eq" data-events="mutate">
    <div class="clearfix show-for-large-only show-for-medium-only show-for-small-only"/>
    <div class="columns large-4 medium-6 small-6" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 229px;">
        <div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_GridWidgetRegions_v2_GridWidgetRegions_v2_col_0_CTATile4_CtaCol" class="cta-col padding-bottom-55" style="background-color:#155067;">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="columns large-4 medium-6 small-6" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 229px;">
        <div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_GridWidgetRegions_v2_GridWidgetRegions_v2_col_1_CTATile5_CtaCol" class="cta-col padding-bottom-55" style="background-color:#155067;">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix show-for-medium-only show-for-small-only"/>
    <div class="columns large-4 medium-6 small-6" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 229px;">
        <div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_GridWidgetRegions_v2_GridWidgetRegions_v2_col_2_CTATile6_CtaCol" class="cta-col padding-bottom-55" style="background-color:#155067;">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix show-for-large-only"/>
    <div class="columns large-4 medium-6 small-6" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 229px;">
        <div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_GridWidgetRegions_v2_GridWidgetRegions_v2_col_3_CTATile7_CtaCol" class="cta-col padding-bottom-55" style="background-color:#155067;">
        
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix show-for-medium-only show-for-small-only"/>
    <div class="columns large-4 medium-6 small-6" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 229px;">
        <div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_GridWidgetRegions_v2_GridWidgetRegions_v2_col_4_CTATile8_CtaCol" class="cta-col padding-bottom-55" style="background-color:#155067;">
        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css is as follows

```
.row.with-right-border .small-6:nth-child(even) {
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

However, the clearfix divs are causing it to not read the even/odd **nth-child** of the class .small-6.

What do I need to use to make this work the way I need?

Comment: If you already know which element to style, you can do `nth-child(3)` but there is no way to filter by class. I think `nth-of-class` exists but is only supported by Safari so it's pretty useless. However, if you use `clearfix` for line breaks with `float` elements, you may want to use `flexbox` or `grid` and get rid of those `clearfix` elements altogether